# WordPress npm run build and start only outputs wp-scripts start but does nothing

Tags: block-editor

I made a WordPress plugin with 3 blocks. The package.json looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
        "build": "wp-scripts build",
        "format": "wp-scripts format",
        "lint:css": "wp-scripts lint-style",
        "lint:js": "wp-scripts lint-js",
        "start": "wp-scripts start",
        "packages-update": "wp-scripts packages-update",
        "build:review-box": "wp-scripts build blocks/review-box/src/index.js --output-path=blocks/review-box/build/",
        "start:review-box": "wp-scripts start blocks/review-box/src/index.js --output-path=blocks/review-box/build/",
        "build:random-game": "wp-scripts build blocks/random-game/src/index.js --output-path=blocks/random-game/build/",
        "start:random-game": "wp-scripts start blocks/random-game/src/index.js --output-path=blocks/random-game/build/",
        "build:game-list": "wp-scripts build blocks/game-list/src/index.js --output-path=blocks/game-list/build/",
        "start:game-list": "wp-scripts start blocks/game-list/src/index.js --output-path=blocks/game-list/build/"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@wordpress/block-editor": "^8.0.13",
        "@wordpress/blocks": "^11.1.5",
        "@wordpress/i18n": "^4.2.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@wordpress/scripts": "^19.2.2"
    }
```

When I run this:

```
npm run start:random-game
```

I only see this output and nothing else:

```
> game-review@0.1.0 start:random-game
> wp-scripts start blocks/random-game/src/index.js --output-path=blocks/random-game/build/
```

Before I could use npm run start:random-game or npm run build:game-list to build and run the script for each blog and something like this happened:

```
asset index.js 2.93 KiB [emitted] [minimized] (name: index)
asset index.asset.php 192 bytes [emitted] (name: index)
Entrypoint index 3.12 KiB = index.js 2.93 KiB index.asset.php 192 bytes
```

This worked fine with before, and works great with any other Gutenberg plugin right now. What am I missing? I tried "npm install @wordpress/scripts --save-dev" to fix this but something seems broken. This is the repository: https://github.com/mtoensing/game-review-block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to pull and get it to run as I would expect.

```bash
$ npm run start:random-game

> game-review@0.1.0 start:random-game C:\Users\...\game-review-block
> wp-scripts start blocks/random-game/src/index.js --output-path=blocks/random-game/build/

<i> [LiveReloadPlugin] Live Reload listening on port 35729
asset index.js 25.4 KiB [emitted] (name: index) 1 related asset
asset style-index.css 858 bytes [emitted] (name: style-index) (id hint: style) 1 related asset
asset index.asset.php 219 bytes [emitted] (name: index)
Entrypoint index 26.4 KiB (17.5 KiB) = style-index.css 858 bytes index.js 25.4 KiB index.asset.php 219 bytes 2 auxiliary assets
runtime modules 4.49 KiB 10 modules
orphan modules 3.61 KiB [orphan] 3 modules
javascript modules 6.11 KiB
  cacheable modules 5.79 KiB
    modules by path ./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/*.js 1.97 KiB 6 modules
    modules by path ./blocks/random-game/src/ 3.81 KiB
      ./blocks/random-game/src/index.js 1000 bytes [built] [code generated]
      ./blocks/random-game/src/style.scss 50 bytes [built] [code generated]
      ./blocks/random-game/src/edit.js 2.31 KiB [built] [code generated]
      ./blocks/random-game/src/save.js 491 bytes [built] [code generated]
  8 modules
css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].use[2]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].use[3]!./blocks/random-game/src/style.scss 47 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.65.0 compiled successfully in 1417 ms
```

I'd try the following

1. `rm -rf node_modules`
2. `npm install --save-dev`

If the above doesn't work check your node version - I use a node version manager that allows switching between versions seamlessly.

Comment: rm -rf node_modules did the trick!